# How to calculate max value for each user and add other attributes

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, grouping

I am trying to get data frame in specific format.
I have 3 attributes user_id, movie_id, movie_ranking.
I want to display best movie_id and ranking for each user based on the maximal ranking.

I guess dplyr library is good for this, but I cannot really get it work.

Comment: Provide [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) and show some coding effort.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

With `dplyr`, we can group by 'user_id', `arrange` the 'movie_ranking' in descending order and `slice` the first row.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(user_id) %>%
    arrange(desc(movie_ranking)) %>%
    slice(1L)
```

A less efficient option would be using `which.max`

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(user_id) %>%
    slice(which.max(movie_ranking))
```

Comment: works great! thanks akrun!